# Cannot create user in Android with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am able to submit data to a "foo table".  I can submit data to any other table, but, suddenly, I cannot create a user.

I am using the exact code from Parse Android documentation.

Any advice?

```
  ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
  user.setUsername("my name");
  user.setPassword("my pass");
  user.setEmail("email@example.com");

  user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

  user.signUpInBackground();
```

Comment: Just fyi,  nothing returned in the exception either

            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                } else {
                    Log.d("AppDebuger Code: ", "dd");
                    Log.d("AppDebuger Code: ", String.valueOf(e.getCode()));
                    Log.d("AppDebuger Message: ", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
                    Log.d("AppDebuger Cause: ", String.valueOf(e.getCause()));
                }
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found someone with a similar problem -

[New to Parse, not able to sign up a ParseUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315002/new-to-parse-not-able-to-sign-up-a-parseuser)

You have to delete enable local datastore

Answer (score 0):

Adding `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();` in your Application class will make sure ParseUser is never null. Add this and try your code. This should work.